# Can't call base object's method directly

Tags: javascript

I have this base class:

```
    function Transition(slide, settings){
        this.slide = slide;
        this.settings = settings;
        this.duration = (this.settings['transitionSpeed'] / 1000) + 's'
    }

    Transition.prototype.removeOrderClasses = function(){
        DomUtil.removeClass(this.slide, 'nd-slide-current');
        DomUtil.removeClass(this.slide, 'nd-slide-next');
        DomUtil.removeClass(this.slide, 'nd-slide-previous');
    }
```

I derive from it for FadeTransition:

```
    function FadeTransition(slide, settings){
        Transition.call(this, slide, settings);
    }
    FadeTransition.prototype = Object.create(Transition);
    FadeTransition.prototype.constructor = FadeTransition;

    FadeTransition.prototype.in = function(){
        this.removeOrderClasses(); //KABOOM
    }
```

`this.removeOrderClasses` throws an error, as the method cannot be found. However, `this.prototype.removeOrderClasses` is found.

Is this how I should be referencing these functions? If I have multiple levels of inheritance, won't I need to write these sorts of cumbersome statements: `this.prototype.prototype.someMethod()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the wrong object to `Object.create`. It should be:

```
FadeTransition.prototype = Object.create(Transition.prototype);
```

Otherwise you are creating a new object that inherits from `Transition`, the function, not from `Transition.prototype`, where all the prototype methods are defined.

---

That's also why `this.prototype.removeOrderClasses` "works". Normal objects don't have a prototype property (try it out: `console.log(({}).prototype)`), but `this.prototype` refers to `Transition.prototype`.